# I want to add image as background for grid in windows store app but i hava an error

Tags: c#, .net

I have an exception like URI format exception, why it is occurring although it is correct

```
ImageBrush img1 = new ImageBrush();
img1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/new.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 2):

That URI won't work for Windows Store applications (RT/Metro).

Try this:

```
new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/new.jpg");
```